# Passing --env variable with 'docker run -e SOME_VAR=some_val' is not working

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

Here is a snippet of my Dockerfile:

```
ENV LOG_AS_JSON=false

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djson.logging=$LOG_AS_JSON"
```

When I try to pass the variable with the following command it is still set to the default value 'false':

```
docker run --detach --publish 8080:8080 --env LOG_AS_JSON=true --name app-json some_name:latest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first issue is that the expression is already evaluated at build time. So what's in the image is

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djson.logging=false"
```

To prevent the build-time evaluation, you can use single quotes, so the statement becomes

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS='-Djson.logging=$LOG_AS_JSON'
```

Then, to get the container to actually replace the variable, you can use the `eval` command. Here I set a new variable, 'foo', to echo the contents of the variable and then `eval` the new variable and it prints out `-Djson.logging=true`.

```
docker run --rm -e LOG_AS_JSON=true <image name> /bin/sh -c 'foo="echo $JAVA_OPTS"; eval $foo'
```